# Does Brouwer's theorem holds in every closed path-connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Here is an assignment my professor handed out:

> Let $X$ be some object crushed from a closed ball $B^2$.
>
> Let $f:X\rightarrow X$ be a continuous function.
>
> Then, there exists $x$ such that $f(x)=x$.

As you can see, the statement is really naive and informal.

I have no idea how to tackle this problem.. Please help

EDIT:

[image]

Actually, he simply drew this and asked us to prove $f$ has a fixed point

Comment: I don't think "crushed" is standard terminology, what do you mean by that? Deformation retract?

Comment: As for the question in the title, the answer is no: look at $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ and $f(x) = -x$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I just edited it. No I did't mean deformation retract.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I don't know whether there is a formal way to decribe this picture..

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that by crushed, you're professor just means homeomorphic.

We suppose $X$ is homeomorphic to $B^2$ so there exists $j : B^2 \to X$ a homeomorphism, and $j^{-1} : X \to B^2$ is also a homeomorphism. We're given a continuous map $f : X \to X$, so let's consider the following chain of maps: $$B^2 \xrightarrow j X \xrightarrow f  X \xrightarrow{j^{-1}} B^2$$

Define $h : B^2 \to B^2$ by $h = j^{-1} \circ f \circ j$ which is continuous since the composition of continuous maps is continuous.

By the Brouwer Fixed-Point Theorem, there exists $x \in B^2$ such that $h(x) = x$. In particular, $(j^{-1} \circ f \circ j)(x) = x$. But this means $f \big( j(x) \big) = j(x)$.

Hence $j(x)$ is the point in $X$ that satisfied the requirement you wanted.